# ¿ DataSet coger indice de filas de una tabla que coincida con nombre = valor?

Tags: asp.net

Dado un `DataSet` con nombre de tabla = tabla1 tengo varias filas. De todas las filas quiero seleccionar el índice o indices de la que contenga el elemento con el nombre de elemento = elemento y valor = valorA

Con:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables["tabla1"].Rows.count;
```

obtengo el numero total de filas

Con:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables["tabla1"].Rows[2]["elemento"];
```

obtengo un valor

Necesito implementar un método que dado valor y su key = "elemento" me devuelva el índice 2 o índices que coincidan.

¿ Es decir como lo hago para que me devuelva el index del elemento de las filas que sea igual a valorA ?

¿Es posible hacerlo sin for o foreach ?

Comment: no creo que sea posible sin loops

Comment: utilizando programación funcional o declarativa creo que si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes buscar todas las filas que contengan ese valor con LINQ y luego ver el indice de cada fila con la colección de filas

```
string claveColumna = "elemento";
string valorAbuscar = "asd";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow[] drList = dt.Select($"{claveColumna} like %{valorAbuscar}%");
List<int> indices = new List<int>();
Array.ForEach(drList, dr => indices.Add(dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr)));
```

Comment: Mas o menos esto era lo que buscaba. Pero pensaba que era mas intuitivo. Hay un método que es Find no se si usando algo como ds.Tables["tabla"].Rows.Find("valor") .Pero esto no funciona

Comment: el `Rows.Find` es para buscar por la clave de la columna, para buscar por valores debes usar el Select

Comment: Ok gracias por tu ayuda